# Logging pattern in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, logging

How do I set the logging file pattern to something like `server.log.2017-12-22.gz`?

As of now in my application.properties file, I have set the logging pattern to:

```
logging.pattern.file= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd } [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"

logging.file=/var/opt/VS_Logs/server.log
```

But I need to store the files in the following format: `server.log.2017-12-22.gz`

Comment: not sure what you are asking, you want the file to be named server.log.2017-12-22.gz? or the pattern in which it is written in that file?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for wrong explanation. I want to encode it in .gz format. As of now spring boot is saving logs as server.log. But I want to encode say yesterday`s log then it should convert it to server.log.date.gz

Comment: How in the world Principal Software Engineer cannot google how to zip log file in Logback? I can't believe it, as it was answered thousand times with detailed examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you want custom rolling and triggering policies, you can no longer rely on Spring boot's logging configuration, and you have to use the vendor specific logging configuration. Here is an example using Logback and a [`TimeBasedRollingPolicy`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html):

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>server.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>server.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd } [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Logback will automatically gzip it when you use the `.gz` extension. If you save this file as `logback.xml` and put it on your classpath, Spring boot will automatically detect it, otherwise, you can use the `logging.config` property:

```
logging.config=classpath:logback.xml
```

Comment: Thanks @g00glen00b this looks great. How and where to mention the path where we want to save log file.

Comment: The same place where you configure the filename, so if you change it into `<file>my/folder/server.log</file>` it will log to that specific folder. You can also provide absolute paths if you want to.

Comment: It worked. But somehow console log on eclipse are not getting printed. I have enabled it in application.properties as logging.pattern.console= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n" . Please let me know to to enable that also

Comment: That's because you have to configure either everything in `logback.xml` or nothing. There's a [`ConsoleAppender`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender) for Logback to log things to the console. Alternatively, if you only want to log to a file on specfic servers, you can externalize `logback.xml` and only set the `logging.config` property when you're deploying on a server.